# i want to import json products to woocommerce

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have products in JSON file almost 95 MB. these are all 5000 products. all I want to upload the products to woo-commerce WordPress. I convert the JSON to CSV but not get the things. I need the only JSON to WordPress woo commerce import guidance. I search youtube and every other thigs but not succeeded yet.

Comment: Split the csv into small size and try.

Comment: @Earid where i upload it in which section. these are all products

Comment: Split them, you can use online tool like https://textfilesplitter.com/ , then try https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/ .

Comment: All are set i m using wp all import pro plugin. But one thing that images are not downloading.

Comment: You need to add image file names on csv column, and separately upload images.

Comment: Its 5000 products and i cant upload it separately

Comment: You can check here Codexdeveloper.com/acetool/shop/

Comment: link not worked, I import bulk upload this way, there might be a json import process, have to wait unless any other community user add their answers.

Comment: https://codexdeveloper.com/acetool/shop/ here is check again please

Comment: can u help me please if i share you login. i really appreciate your help

Comment: I don't know the shortcut, that's the way I know. Wait for any other answer.

Comment: {
    "class": "0",
    "category": "Personal Protective Equipment",
    "item_no": "CT88",
    "item": "CONTACTLESS INFRARED THERMOMETER",
    "image": "assets/img/items/CT88.jpg",
    "description": "<P>Convenient Memory Feature: You can store

Comment: it is like that i think it must have url of the website then it will be download otherwise not

Comment: Yes, you need to upload image , then replace the image's WordPress URLs with CSV's path, then import that.

Comment: oooh man these are 5000+ products i have to do a lot of effort but let me check

Comment: let wait for any other ans

Comment: There should be an automated process, I did this with 300 products, so manual works wasn't a big hassle, Good Luck.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: i find the problem. the problem is that with the image link is not proper in the json file. the linkin the json file is something like that assets/img/items/T-HEXM.jpeg so what i did is change the link to www.abc.xyz/assets/img/items/T-HEXM.jpeg now i get all the imagees. thank you for your support. i m just sharing becasue it helpfull for you. you also ask i did manually so no need to do it manually. just follow the path and then you will get the results